# How to filter an array of objects and merge them into a single object?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the following array of objects into a an object format when topic = 'favorites'.

Original Format

```
const events = [
      {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000066928',
        datetime: 2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z
      },
      {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000061499',
        datetime: 2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z
      },
      {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000102733',
        datetime: 2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z
      },
      {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000107928',
        datetime: 2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z
      }
    ]
```

Converted Format

```
{
    1000000002: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
    1000000008: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
    1000000009: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00',
    1000000010: '2020-01-24T20:46:05+11:00'
},
```

I've been trying to work with the following but I'm a bit off.

```
events.filter((event) => event.topic === "favorites").map(receiver, datetime => receiver: datetime)
```

Comment: how do you get the result from given data?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to workout... I need to get from the original format to the converted format

Comment: The syntax on the `map` is wrong, it should be `{ receiver, datetime }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line reducer should be sufficient

```js
const events = [{
    topic: 'favorites',
    receiver: '1000066928',
    datetime: "2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z"
  },
  {
    topic: 'favorites',
    receiver: '1000061499',
    datetime: "2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z"
  },
  {
    topic: 'blocked',
    receiver: '1000102733',
    datetime: "2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z"
  },
  {
    topic: 'blocked',
    receiver: '1000107928',
    datetime: "2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z"
  }
]

console.log(events
  .reduce((acc, val) => val.topic === "favorites" && 
    { ...acc, [val.receiver]: val.datetime } ||
    acc, {}));
```

Comment: I find the expression `<condition> && <if true> || <if false>` a little bit unintuitive. Using the ternary operator feels more idiomatic: `<condition> ? <if true> : <if false>`.

Comment: It's a matter of usage I suppose: if the code is shared with others, readability may be important. In that case I would actually opt for `if (val.topic === "favorites") {...} else {...}`. Otherwise  boolean short circuit or ternary (in this case) are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter and map the entries for a new object.

```js
const
    events = [{ topic: 'favorites', receiver: '1000066928', datetime: '2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z' }, { topic: 'favorites', receiver: '1000061499', datetime: '2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z' }, { topic: 'blocked', receiver: '1000102733', datetime: '2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z' }, { topic: 'blocked', receiver: '1000107928', datetime: '2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z' }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(events
        .filter(({ topic }) => topic === 'favorites')
        .map(({ receiver, datetime }) => [receiver, datetime])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your given data doesn't correspond to your expected output *by value*. But I assume the format is correct. It also seems like, in your result, you want the dates in ISO string form. But in your source object they are kept as a `Date` object. So I'll be assuming the source array does indeed contain `Date` objects.

With that said, you really just have to turn every object into `[receiver, datetime]` (after filtering) and do [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on the result

```js
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    events
        .filter(event => event.topic === 'favorites')
        .map(({ receiver, datetime }) => [receiver, datetime.toISOString()])
);
```

```js
const events = [
    {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000066928',
        datetime: new Date('2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000061499',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000102733',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000107928',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z'),
    },
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    events
        .filter(event => event.topic === 'favorites')
        .map(({ receiver, datetime }) => [receiver, datetime.toISOString()])
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `reduce` you can built an object that will be updated in every iteration.

```
const output = events
  .filter((event) => event.topic === "favorites")
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {...acc, [cur.receiver]: cur.datetime };
  }, {});
console.log(output);
/* {
  '1000061499': '2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z',
  '1000066928': '2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z'
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce and filter for this in combination

I had to do a string out of datetime otherwise it would result in an error.

```js
const events = [
      {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000066928',
        datetime: "2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z"
      },
      {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000061499',
        datetime: "2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z"
      },
      {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000102733',
        datetime: "2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z"
      },
      {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000107928',
        datetime: "2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z"
      }
    ]

const result = events
  .filter((event) => event.topic === "favorites")
  .reduce((accum, element) => {
    return {...accum, [element.receiver]: element.datetime };
  }, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```
const filteredEvents = events.reduce((a, b) => {
  return b.topic === 'favorites' 
    ? {...a, [b.receiver] : b.datetime} 
    : a
}, {})

console.log(filteredEvents);

/*
{
  '1000061499': '2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z',
  '1000066928': '2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z'
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use case for using the `.reduce()` prototype function on the array. This will save you multiple repeated iterations with fewer lines of code.

The example data doesn't seem to match but I am assuming the format is correct.

In your case, you can use `reduce` like this -

```
const events = [
    {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000066928',
        datetime: new Date('2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'favorites',
        receiver: '1000061499',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000102733',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z'),
    },
    {
        topic: 'blocked',
        receiver: '1000107928',
        datetime: new Date('2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z'),
    },
];

const result = events.reduce((acc, event) => {
  if (b.topic === 'favorites') {
    return {...acc, [event.receiver] : b.datetime};
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

To better understand how reduce works - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reduce-f47a7da511a9/

Answer (score 0):

A single reduce combined with a topic filter should be enough and some answers have already demonstrated how to do this.

This answer does that but adds:

1. Currying. So you can apply the transformation to other topics
2. The comma operator instead of the spread operator. Depending on how big the list to process is, [the spread operator can quickly become a performance bottleneck](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/97eb4b3f1600773db59406d39f3f9cd7)

```js
const transform =
  topic => xs =>
    xs.reduce( (o, x) =>
                  (x.topic === topic
                    ? (o[x.receiver] = x.datetime, o)
                    : o), {});
```

What's going on here?

The function is curried; it takes a topic then a list to process. This means you can build two topic-processing functions:

```js
const favorites = transform('favorites');
const blocked = transform('blocked');
```

These two functions now only wait for a list to be processed. Assuming `list` is the same as your `events` array:

```js
favorites(list);
// { 1000061499: "2017-01-03T19:15:04.000Z"
// , 1000066928: "2016-11-26T21:43:54.000Z"
// }

blocked(list);
// { 1000102733: "2017-01-05T17:04:15.000Z"
// , 1000107928: "2017-01-06T17:17:05.000Z"
// }
```